# In my Blazor server side app's razor page i have an iframe that should scroll to page end when razor page is loaded. How can I do that?

Tags: iframe, scroll, blazor-server-side, razor-pages

In my Blazor server side app's razor page i have an iframe that is linked to a .txt log file. As the log file is very large, I want that the iframe should scroll to page end automatically when razor page is loaded. How can I do that?

(The latest alarm is added to the end of the page and I do not want to modify the log file)

in my simplified razor page I have tried following but didn't work.

```
<body>
  <iframe src="/main_log.txt" width="1500" height="800" frameborder="0" onload="scrollTo(1,99999)"></iframe>   
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onLoad’ event needs to talk to the iframe. It would be something like.

```
 document
   .getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]
   .contentWindow
   .scrollTo({top: 999999, behavior: 'smooth'})
```

Comment: I tried but unfortunately, it didin't work. But I think this is the correct direction. I am still trying around this solution

Comment: Just updated the answer with another version that I just tested

Comment: Great!!! Worked es expected. Have a good weekend David ! :-) And the "smooth" behaivour was an additional surprise